# Best way to Manage Junction Tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a PHP application where I want to enter many-to-many relationships between products and categories. Everything I put into the database will be manual and my database structure is:

```
--TABLES--    
Products - (Product_ID, Name, etc.)
Categories - (Category_ID, Name, etc.)
Product_Categories (Product_Category_ID, Product_ID, Category_ID) 
*this is my junction table 
*the Product/Category IDs in this table reference those in the other tables.
```

Currently when entering in relationships manually, I have to think: which product is product #7 again, and which category is category #8? now there is just a handful but this will be incredibly cumbersome when there are more.

My question is: If I'm manually entering relationships into the junction table, what is the best way to manage this process.  Do I need to create my own php page that visualizes these relationships, is there an application better than phpmyadmin (or a feature in it) for this, can I somehow show other table info related to ID's in phpmyadmin?

I'm new to all of this, so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Imagine if `name` was the PK instead of `product_id`. Would this make the process less cumbersome? Also, while you're thinking about that, note that product_category_id serves no apparent purpose.

Comment: It would, I thought of that, but wasn't sure if referencing unique auto incrementing product ID's would be a better way to go about it.  If not, then that is certainly a solution. Are there any drawbacks to doing it that way?

Comment: I was actually trying to make the opposite point! (fail) Whether you're relating names or ids, you still have a task that is to some degree 'manual', by which I mean that some level of application-level code will be useful. So, if you're writing code to pair names with categories, you might as well extend it to pair category ids with product ids!

Comment: Makes sense.  I think writing some app code is probably the best solution in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin wiki has a page describing [how to link foreign key values from tables with fewer than 200 rows](http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/FAQ_6.21). Maybe this will help your category problem, but probably not your product id problem.

(Personally I think your instinct to write a data entry app in php or whatever was correct, but here is at least an attempt to find a feature within PMA.